# Converting textbox string to float?

Tags: c++, textbox, c++-cli

I'm basically trying to write a basic converter in visual studio 2008, and I have 2 text boxes, one which gets input from the user, and one which gives output with the result. When I press the button I want the input from the first textbox to multiply by 4.35 then display in the 2nd textbox. This is my code in the button code so far:

```
             String^ i1 = textBox1->Text;
             float rez = (i1*4.35)ToString;
             textBox2->Text = rez;
```

However I'm getting these errors:

```
f:\microsoft visual studio 9.0\projects\hellowin\hellowin\Form1.h(148) : error C2676: binary '*' : 'System::String ^' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
f:\microsoft visual studio 9.0\projects\hellowin\hellowin\Form1.h(148) : error C2227: left of '->ToString' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
f:\microsoft visual studio 9.0\projects\hellowin\hellowin\Form1.h(149) : error C2664: 'void System::Windows::Forms::Control::Text::set(System::String ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'float' to 'System::String ^'
```

Please help I'm going insane on how ridiculously difficult it is to get some input from a textbox in C++. I've googled every error I had and nothing useful came up, I've been searching answers for an hour already, please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fixing it for you,

```
         String^ i1 = textBox1->Text;
         float rez = (float)(Convert::ToDouble(i1)*4.35);
         textBox2->Text = rez.ToString();
```

Basically, you want to convert your string to an actual number, do the math, and then make it back into a string for displaying purposes.

Comment: It works! Thank-you. I found in Stackoverflow in 10 minutes what I was looking for an hour. Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, I'm a fan of this site too :)

Comment: Yes it's truly amazing, I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes (When the timer lets me do it)
EDIT: Accepted, thanks once more.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to multiply a string by a double and there is no operator that defines how to do that. You need to convert your string to a double first, and then use that in the calculation.

Then, you're trying to assign a string to a float, which again is nonsense.. You need to calculate the float, then convert it to a string when assigning it to the textbox text field.

Something like:

```
String^ i1 = textBox1->Text;
float rez = (Convert::ToDouble(i1)*4.35);
textBox2->Text = rez.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks, but my question was already answered, still you deserve a +1 for your effort.

Comment: Yeah, you gotta be quick on here! :)