# C++ Converting textbox content to a Float

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c++-cli

Tried carefully code from this thread

[Converting textbox string to float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8718048/converting-textbox-string-to-float/8718108#8718108)

Tried to leavemy question in a comment, but yet not allowed to do so... 
The summary of that goes like having two text boxes, taking data from first, doing something, and returning the result to the second.

```
String^ i1 = Textbox1->Text;
float rez = (float)(Convert::ToDouble(i1)*4);
Textbox2->Text = rez.ToString();
```

and it works pretty good unless `Textbox1` got a float within itself (upd. it works ok with '65', but doesn't work with '65.5').
Trying to execute that code - crushes a program

```
>   Calc.exe!Calc::Form1::Button0_Click(System::Object^ sender = 0x01b29c58, System::EventArgs^ e = 0x01b45e40) Line 123 + 0x30 byte    C++
```

Comment: _"and it works pretty good unless Textbox1 got a float within itself."_ Uhm, what??

Comment: it goes ok with an integer but not ok if it's something like '65.5' inside a textbox

Comment: You should investigate with the debugger, where exaclty that _crash_ occurs, and tell us please. Did you mean to tell us your program throws an exception on the line `float rez = (float)(Convert::ToDouble(i1)*4);`?

Comment: Yes, line 123 is that particular line. it throws an exception "unexpected input format" or something (sorry if i did the translation not correctly)

Comment: I'm just making a wild guess: What happens if you have something like `65,5` in that textbox? It appears to me like you're having a problem with the `.` or `,` are used as decimal point for different country/language settings.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ you should post your wildguess as an answer, dude... it somehow worked)))

Comment: Seems Dmitry did already :) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Convert::ToDouble](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zh1hkw6k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

> Using the ToDouble(String) method is equivalent to passing value to the Double.Parse(String) method. Value is interpreted by using the formatting conventions of **the current thread culture**.

So, you need

1. Catch possible exceptions

   ```
   try {
       float rez = (float)(Convert::ToDouble(i1)*4);
   }
   catch (FormatException) {
       // handle format error exception here
   }
   catch (OverflowException) {
       // handle overflow exception here
   }
   ```
2. Use [IFormatProvider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/9s9ak971%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)